# How to decrease space between headings?

Tags: html, css

I make a div and inside I make headings but when shown the headings are outside the div. How do I decrease the heading margins?

Here is my code:

```
<div id="left" style="width:300px; height:100px; float:left; margin:5px 40px 0;">
<h5 id="companyname">{{companyname}}</h5>
<h5 id="companyaddress">{{companyaddress}},{{companycity}},</h5>
<h5 id="companycountry">{{companycountry}}</h5>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
#companyname{
    text-align:left;
    font-size:13px;
}

#companyaddress{
    text-align:left;
    width:68%;
    font-size:13px;
}

#companycountry{
    text-align:left;
    font-size:13px;
}
```

Comment: It's generally recommended to move all styles to external style sheets for ease of updating, clarity for future developers, and to separate content types (HTML != CSS).  If at all possible, move the styles on `#left` to an external CSS file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XtcgA/)**

**css**

```
h5{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
h5
{
line-height:10px;
}
```

i have used 10px you can use values accordingly to your need

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pwncx/9/)

Setting up the margins and padding accordingly is also a good option

```
h5 {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Question:

> how to decrease heading margins?

Answer:

```
h5 { margin: 0px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two Option.

1. Increasing the Height of the div
2. give css for h5 like this because by default h5 element takes some margin

   *h5{ margin:0px}*